# Problemas de redireccionamiento

Tags: php, wordpress, url, cpanel, enlace

Consulta bueno he hecho un redireccionamiento a las paginas de los subdominios, por ejemplo este es un subdomino. tazas.cafetera.com y la url que vaya es https://www.cafetera.com/tazas/ y si me redije correctamente con el redirects en el cpanel, pero si lo  pongo asi https://www.cafetera.com/tazas ya no funciona alguien me ayudaria como hacerlo es wordpress.